# Knockout input-binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I am trying to update an application which didn't use Knockout earlier. Few input fields gets data from the server/database as we change the select option. Now, I am trying to generate a report based on the filled input fields using Knockout. But when these input fields get data from database,it is not being updated on the UI.
For example,

```html
<input type = "text" id = "ip1" data-bind = "value:ip1"></input>
```

gets data from database.

In the report I am trying to update the value received from database.

```html
<tr><td>Left Margin:</td><td><strong data-bind="text:ip1"></strong></td></tr>
```

View Model:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  self = this;
  self.ip1 = ko.observable();
};
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

The function for retrieving the data from the database is written separately using JavaScript, Ajax, PHP, xmlhttp.

Now when I am changing the select option, the input fields are getting updated but the on the report, the data is not being updated.

Comment: How are you processing the new data from the server? You'll need to set `ip1` using `vm.ip1(newValue)` for everything to keep working. You should **not** try to update values through code via the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

so it sounds like knockout is unaware that your elements have changed.  can you force a change via jquery after your inputs change from your unbound event.

```
jQuery('#myinput').change();
```

here is a fiddle I did where I have an unbound button click that changes the value of a bound input box.  https://jsfiddle.net/othkss9s/30/

here is the javascript

```
function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.test = ko.observable("test");
};

var myViewModel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
  $('#mybutton').click(function(event) {
    $('#myinput').val('changed from jquery');
    jQuery('#myinput').change();
  });

});
```

here is the html

```
<p>
  <input data-bind="textInput: test" id="myinput"> the value is:
  <label data-bind="text: test"></label>
</p>

<p>
  <button id="mybutton">
    change the value using jquery
  </button>
</p>
```